# per-paragraph commenting system

Tags: content-management-system, comments

I'm very interested in the emerging trend of comments-per-paragraph systems (also called "annotations systems"), such as the ones implemented by [medium.com](https://medium.com/thoughts-on-creativity/91b443104b92) and [qz.com](http://qz.com/111748/you-can-now-leave-annotations-in-the-margins-of-quartz/) and i'm looking at the idea of developing one for my own.

Question: it seems they are mainly implemented via javascript, that runs through the text's html paragraphs uniquely identified by an id attribute (or, in the case of Medium, a name attribute). Does it mean their CMS actually store each paragraph as a separate entry in the database? Seems overly complex to me, but otherwise, how do they manage the fact that a paragraph can be deleted, edited or moved around in the overall text? How would the unique id be preserved if the author changes the paragraph?
How is that unique id logically structured? (post_id + position_in_post)?

Thank you for your insights...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I can't speak to the medium side, but as one of the developers for Quartz, I can give insight into how qz.com annotations work.

The annotations code is custom php code and is independent of the CMS for publishing articles (wordpress VIP). We do indeed store a reference to each paragraph as a row in the database, in order to track any updates to the article content. We call this an annotation thread and when a user saves an annotation the threadId gets stored along with the annotation.

We do not have a unique id stored on the wordpress side for each paragraph, instead we store the paragraphs relative position in that article (nodeIndex “3" and nodeSelector “p” ==  the third p-tag in the content body for a given article) and the javascript determines where exactly to place the annotation block. We went this route to avoid heavier customizations on the wordpress side, though depending on your CMS it may be easier to address this directly in the CMS code and add unique ids in the html before sending to the client.

Every time an update to an article is published, each paragraph in the updated article is compared against what was previously stored with the annotation threads for that article. If the position and paragraph text do not match up, it attempts to find the paragraph that is the closest match and update the row for that thread and new threads are created and deleted where appropriate. All of this is handled server side whenever changes are published to an article.

A couple of alternate implications that are also worth looking at are Gawker's Kinja text annotations (currently in use on Jalopnik) and    the word-for-word annotations of rapgenius.com.

Comment: thanks Sam, your reply brings very interesting insights. Best of luck for Quartz!

Comment: Maybe you want to open-source your code? ... I am kidding. Thanks for the insight. This will give many developers an inspiration how to implement such a system by themselves. I am sure somebody will release a smart third party service for inline commenting. Question of time :)

Comment: Ah, somebody implemented Disqus this way, check out the source code at https://github.com/tsi/inlineDisqussions

Answer (score 5):

(disclaimer: I'm a [factlink](http://factlink.com/) dev.)

I work for a company trying to allow per-paragraph (or per-phrase) commenting on arbitrary sites.  Essentially, you've got two choices to identify the anchor of a comment.

1. Remember the structure of the page (e.g. some path from a root to a paragraph), and place comments at the same position next time.
2. Identify the content of the paragraph and place comments near identical or similar content next time.

Both systems have their downsides, but you pretty much need to go with option 2 if you want a robust system.  Structural identification is fragile in the face of changing structure.  Especially irrelevant changes such theming or the precise html tags used can significantly impact the "path".  When that happens, you really can't fix it - unless you inspect the content, i.e. option (2).

Sam describes what comes down to a server-side content-based in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19760343/42921).  Purely client-side content-based matching is what [factlink](http://factlink.com/) and (IIRC) [hypothesis](http://hypothes.is/) use.  Most browsers support non-standard but fast substring search in page content using either [`window.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.find) or [`TextRange.findText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536422(v=vs.85).aspx).  Alternatively, you could walk the DOM, which is slower but gives you the flexibility to implement (e.g.) fuzzy matching.

It may seem like client-side matching is overkill or complex, but really, it's simpler: it's a very robust way to decouple your content-management from your commenting.  Neither is really simple, so decoupling those concerns can be a win.

Answer (score 4):

I had created a fiddle on the same lines to demonstrate power of JQuery during a training session.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/fotuzlab/Lwhu5/

Might help as a starting point along with Sam's detailed and useful insights. You get the value of textfield  in Jquery function where you can send it across to your CMS using ajax/APIs.

PS: The function is not production ready. Its only meant as a starting point. A little tweaking will make it usable.

Answer (score 3):

I've recently [published a post](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-have-paragraph-commenting-just-like-medium) on how to do this with WordPress building on an existing plugin.

Like qz.com, I assign paragraph ids on the client and then provide that info to WordPress to store as comment meta when a new comment is created. I used hashing of the paragraph text to create the id which means that the order of paragraphs is unimportant but does mean that if a paragraph is edited then any associated comments become orphaned.

At first I thought this was an issue but thinking about it, if a reader comments on a paragraph then editing that text subsequently seems a little sneaky.

The code is freely available on GitHub if you feel like forking it and enhancing it.

Answer (score 2):

There is one other wordpress plugin called "commentpress" which exist since a long time.
I use an old version of this plugin for my blog and it's work very well.

You can choose to comment per lines or per paragraphs, and ergonomics is really thinking!

A demo here:
http://futureofthebook.org/
and all the code is on github:
https://github.com/IFBook/commentpress-core

After a quick look on the code, it seems they use the second approch like @Eamon Nerbonne explains on [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19477494/per-paragraph-commenting-system#22682246).
They parse each paragraphs to make a signature based on the first char of each words. [Here](https://github.com/IFBook/commentpress-core/blob/master/commentpress-core/class_commentpress_parser.php#L1765) is the function to do that.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone comes looking in here, I've implemented a medium like functionality as a Django app. 
It is open source and can be found as [package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=pkg_edit&name=pi-annotations) on Pypi, and on [github](https://github.com/PirateLearner/annotations).

I used one of my other apps, [blogging](https://github.com/PirateLearner/blogging) to allocate unique Paragraph IDs to each content object (currently we're only looking at `<p>` tags) and puts uses some extra internal meta data in the backend while storing it in DB (MySQL currently, but what we've done is `JSON`ed the Blob, this method is more natively suited for a document oriented DBs). The frontend is mainly jQuery driven with `REST` API plugging the backend with the frontend.

I took cues from this post, but then rejected the creation of some kind of digest value from paragraph because content *can* change. What I wanted was to preserve the *annotations* as long as the paragraph was not completely over-written. In the complete over-write case, I provided for collection of the annotations in an orphaned bucket.

More in these [tutorials](http://piratelearner.com/en/C/course/computer-science/django/annotations-tutorial-part-1-per-paragraph-commenting/10/)

A legacy version of the same is running on those tutorials pages, that was the first revision. (But you won't be able to post without logging in, but you could always login using social accounts to check it out :-) )